# Access dynamic data from website

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, swift, parsing

I'm working on an app that takes data from an external URL. Im creating this with Swift and have reached a sticking point. I am a new programmer..hope you guys can help steer me in the right direction.

Looking at the HTML for the website, the data I need is being displayed with  JavaScript in a responsive table. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Also, I found these comments in the jQuery script for the pages resources. Don't know what it means.

*Can't do this because several apps including ASP.NET trace
  the stack via arguments.caller.callee and Firefox dies if
 you try to trace through "use strict" call chains.*

Comment: This is simply too vague to answer. However, I can tell you that if you want your web app data available in your Swift app, you will need to create/provide an api on top of the web app for Swift to send requests to. In theory, your api would simply return the data that currently populates the responsive table.

Comment: @Jbird That only applies if you control the web app. You can't create an API within a site that you don't control.

Comment: This sounds like a typical web-scraping job. Suggest you look at a combination of Watin to controll a browser and CSQuery to extract content in a *jQuery kind of way*.

Comment: I have created an API using KimonaLabs.com  that outputs JSON and can get certain data to present well within the app (via swifyJSON).    I'm looking for a more generic way of "extracting the data" from a particular file folder in the external website.

Answer (score 0):

> Looking at the HTML for the website, the data I need is being displayed with javascript in a responsive table. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

- Check the AJAX requests generated by the external URL via the browser developer tools
- Find the one which is used to return the JSON data used in the table
- Call the JSON URL in the Swift code instead of the HTML URL

> Don't know what it means.
>
> Can't do this because several apps including ASP.NET trace the stack via arguments.caller.callee and Firefox dies if you try to trace through "use strict" call chains

For strict mode, use `error.stack` as an alternative to `arguments.caller.callee` to generate a stack trace. For example:

```js
function foo() { 
"use strict";
try
  {
  console.log(arguments.caller.callee);
  }
catch(e)
  {
  console.log(e.stack);
  }
} 

foo();
```

**References**

- [MSDN: stack Property (Error) (JavaScript)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh699850.aspx)
- [MDN: Error.prototype.stack](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/stack)
- [V8 Wiki: Stack Trace API](https://github.com/v8/v8/wiki/Stack%20Trace%20API)
- [A Compact Representation of Captured Stack Frames for SpiderMonkey](http://fitzgeraldnick.com/2015/04/10/compact-stacks-in-spidermonkey.html)
- [Targeting Edge vs. Legacy Engines in JsRT APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn903710)
- [Hosting the JavaScript Runtime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn249552)
- [OSX 10.10 Release Notes: JavaScript for Automation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/InterapplicationCommunication/RN-JavaScriptForAutomation/Articles/OSX10-10.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014508-CH109-SW1)
- [Mac Automation Scripting Guide: About Mac Scripting](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/)
- [jQuery Core 3.0 Upgrade Guide, Breaking change: jQuery 3.0 runs in Strict Mode](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#breaking-change-jquery-3-0-runs-in-strict-mode)